# User experience and Agile Modeling

Tags: information-architecture, user-centered-design, documentation, usability-engineering

I have a question regarding architect modeling and how an UX designer can use them to deliver better documentation to the developers/software architects. Has anyone used a component diagram to visualize the physical components in a system?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide more details? Are you referring to techniques used in Iteration 0, tools, ongoing collaboration with the development team or the whole process? This question may be potentially very broad, and even belong rather to pm.stackexchange.com. What I think is, also, that the documentation in agile software development needs to be just enough elaborate to convey the concept. What exactly you use may depend on the type and scale of projects/products you work on.

Comment: Hi @DominikOslizlo,  in OOD & Software architect there are several diagrams to model the system and understand the interconnection between each component. Now from A UX point of view, the requirement gathering and analysis might lead to user flow and other diagrams to show the relation between each element and then illustrate those in design phase. Would architect modeling be any help to UX designer ? what if there's no software architect in the company and there's only back-end developers who has less knowledge about software architect? , i know what i am asking is too broad/fuzzy. Thank you

Comment: @DominikOslizlo should the ux designer think like an architect ? if yes, is it beneficial for the project to have system modeling and design as a part of the documentation ? would any of the following diagram be any beneficial " collaboration, sequence , activity, state diagram , component diagram " ?. hope you got what i am seeking for. your input is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What is being referred to here is perhaps a role called **[System Designer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_design)**.

> Systems design is the process of defining the architecture, modules, interfaces, and data for a system to satisfy specified requirements.